# Anylogic ResourcePoolName.idle() is not update real time?

Tags: anylogic

I use the below command to check availability of ResourcePool:

ResourcePoolName.idle()
ResourcePoolName.busy()

I found that the idle unit (or busy unit) is slowly updated.

When the agent leave the Service block, ResourcePoolName.busy() is still busy and ResourcePoolName.idle() is sill not idle. I need to wait for the agent to enter the next 3rd block so that ResourcePoolName.busy() unit and ResourcePoolName.idle() are updated correctly.

How can we have the idle unit (or busy unit) of the ResourcePool update real time????

Answer (score 1):

Someone recommend me this solution and it work well.

Instead of using A Services Block alone, I uses Services Block + Delay (with delay time = 0). Now when the agent leave the Delay Block, ResourcePoolName.idle() status did updated correctly.